# It doesn't work target black correctly, how can I correct in html?

Tags: php, html

I'm writing with translate:
I have a small code in 1.html:

```
<a href="2.html" target="_black">111111111111111111111111</a>
```

Another code in the new html document 2.html

```
<a href="3.html" target="_black">222222222222222222222222</a>
```

Another code in the new html document 3.html

```
<a href="3.html" target="_black">33333333333333333333333</a>
```

I want it to open on the new page every time I click on the link.
But that doesn't work, how can I change the code to make it work?

When you press  href = 11111 it opens in the new page but when you press  href = 2222 (another page with the name 2.html) already target _black does not work, it does not open in the new page but it opens in all same page.

I hope the translation worked and translated well)

Comment: it's '_blank', not _black 

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>

Comment: thank you, I have not noticed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use _blank to open the link in a new tab. (not _black)

```
<a href="2.html" target="_blank">111111111111111111111111</a>
```

Comment: How could I be so careless :D :D :D :D :D ... I can't believe I didn't notice the mistake . thank you